# Stacking divs horizontally/vertically based on device/screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've come across this problem wherein I have the divisions as follows:
[image]

This is basically a small part of a larger problem, and by understanding how the following works I'm planning to address a bigger problem.

As it can be seen in the above image I have two smaller divisions, each of which occupies half the height of the larger one. However, in tablet I want them to be side by side.

This could be easily addressed by using Bootstrap or other frameworks out there, but my motive in asking this question is to understand the basics of how it can be done from scratch and more importantly understand the core concept.

I had a go at it, Here is my attempt [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cucC/)

Here is the code I've come up with:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="largeImage">  
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/745/292/sports/" alt="large">
</div>

<div class="smallImages">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/214/145/sports/" alt="large">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/214/145/sports/" alt="large">
</div>

.largeImage{
  max-width:740px;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  clear:both;
}

.largeImage img{
  width:100%;
}

.smallImages{
  background-color:lightgray;
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:210px;
}
.smallImages img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.container{
  background-color:whitesmoke ;
  max-width:960px;
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

  body{
    background-color:green;
  }
  
  .smallImages{
    width:100%;

  }
  
  .smallImages img{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left; 
    clear:both;
  }
  .largeImage{
   min-width:100% !important; 
  }
}
```

I do not know if I'm over-complicating things. But I hope someone could clarify it for me here.

To state my question:
How can I stack up the divisions as described in the Image above, without using any frameworks and what needs to be corrected in my attempt?

Comment: media queries for your css so you can position your elements depending on screen size

Comment: [Here is a quick example doing what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/p5L2F/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/josephspens/pNVFw/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/745/365/sports/" alt="large"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/214/145/sports/" alt="large"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/214/145/sports/" alt="large"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 20em) and (max-width: 30em) {
  img {
      width: calc(50% - 0.5em);
  }
  img:first-child {
      width: 100%;
  }
  img:nth-of-type(2n+2) {
      margin-right: 1em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  img {
      width: 25%;
  }
  img:first-of-type {
      width: calc(75% - 1em);
      margin-right: 1em;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly how I wanted it to work.Any specific reason why you are using `em` and not pixels?

Comment: Ems are better for scaling, with a simple change to font-size you can scale entire pages or entire widgets, not just the text size. Also most of the time you're not working in single digit pixels, like for padding and margin, you're working in larger units, so why not make it easier on yourself and say 1em vs 16px or whatever. Makes it easy to do math.

http://css-tricks.com/why-ems/

Answer (score 0):

The screen sizes can be modified, but here is a basic example of how you can do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4cucC/1/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .smallImages{
      max-width:100%;
  }
   .smallImages img{
      max-width: 210px;
   }
}
```